# Defining more efficient logic for given scenario

Tags: java, logic

Got some interesting logic that I am trying to encode in the most efficient and readable way possible. I will lay out the scneario below (with a simulated/dummy context)

I have a data store of banks and their teller reviews (1-5 int field). A teller can optionally have a Customer Choice Winner (CCW) field. My requirements are as below to choose at most 5 tellers for a given bank to display to the user:

1. If a teller is a CCW, choose it. If multiple tellers have CCW, use the teller reviews to break ties
2. When there are no CCW, choose the teller with the greatest 4 rating teller review.

I have to do the above for 5 banks. The logic I was getting was have a for loop to go over the 5 banks and within each loop, go over all tellers for each bank 5 times (to pick 5 tellers). This seems to me to be really inefficient and unclear. Here is what I mean:

```
foreach (Bank b : banks) {
    List<Tellers> tellers = b.getTellers();

    foreach (Teller t : tellers) {
        List<Reviews> reviews = t.getReviews();

        ...// get 4 reviews following the above logic.
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with a clearer and more efficient way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why it can't be done by the database (SQL or whatever)?

Comment: Does tellers contain all of the tellers for all of the banks? Or specifically the tellers for each perspective bank?

Comment: Yes to java 8 and requirements are to not do it in SQL (not up to me)

Comment: @DrewB the b.getTellers() call gets all tellers at the specific bank b.

Comment: You say _" for a given bank"_ but iterate over every bank. Which is it? Is the bank a method parameter or not

Comment: There are 5 banks that this logic must be applied to. So for each of the 5 banks, get the tellers at the current bank being iterated over. Is that more clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Initial description implied the bank object being an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this is to sort the List<Teller>

You will have to define a compare function for the Teller object by implementing the Comparable interface.

This will let you run your algorithm in constant time (O(25) because of 5 tellers for 5 banks, which is really O(1))

At the cost of sorting it the first time, which will be O(nlogn)

Example code for your Teller class:

```
public class Teller implements Comparable
{

    private boolean ccw = false;
    private int rating;

    public boolean hasCCW() { return ccw; }
    public int getRating() { return rating; }

    //... your code

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) 
    {
        Teller that = (Teller)o;
        //if this has ccw and that doesn't, this < that
        if(this.hasCCW() && !that.hasCCW()) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        //else if this does not have ccw, and that does, this > that
        else if(!this.hasCCW() && that.hasCCW())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        //else they both have ccw, so compare ratings
        else
        {
            return Integer.compare(this.getRating(), that.getRating());
        }
    }

}
```

Then, your algorithm will just need to grab the first 5 tellers for each bank.

example:

```
//Sort the tellers:
//ideally, call this only once, and insert future Tellers in order (to maintain ordering)
for(Bank bank : banks)
{
    for(List<Teller> tellers : bank.getTellers())
    {
        Collections.sort(tellers);
    }
}

//then, to get your top tellers:
for(Bank bank : banks)
{
    Teller bestTeller = bank.getTeller(0);
    Teller secondBestTeller = bank.getTeller(1);
    //...
}
```

Comment: That would work if the only thing I was going off of was the teller reviews. But each teller has an additional field for CCW that must also be checked. So say, I have 40 tellers and 5 of them are CCW, algo should return those 5. If there were 3 CCW, algo should return those 3 and the other 2 based on who has the most 4 star reviews. If the teller has 6 CCW, use the review count to return the top 5 tellers out of the 6 with CCW. Would this still work for these scenarios?

Comment: I feel I need a clear way to put this logic into code and then optimize it as a secondary step. Any help there before we go into the runtime analysis?

Comment: Yes it would. You define everything you just said in the compare function. If both Teller objects that are being compared have a CCW, you then check their rating. After the method is defined, you will be able to simply call Collections.sort(tellers), and it will handle the sorting internally.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet on how to accomplish this? First time i am doing anything like this.

Comment: Sure, what part do you need help with? The sorting? Or what to do with the sorted list? Or both

Comment: Essentially the little scenario I laid out in my previous comment, if you could show me how that be encoded in the compare function (ie. sorting part)?

Comment: I added more code. take a look. I don't know what Teller class looks like, so I made a guess (a boolean field for CCW and a integer field for rating)

Comment: Quick clarification here. The review counts are a list of ints so the getRating() wouldnt really work here. What i needed was to choose the teller with the greatest 4 rating teller review. Right now, it compares tellers based on a overall rating since you assumed the getRating() would return a single number rating per teller. In reality, each teller has a list of scores and we want to choose the best one based on the most 4+ review scores within each teller's list of scores

Comment: You should then replace the Integer.compare method call with some code doing what you just described. You should be able to work that out. The compare method is comparing this (the current object) against argument object. If this comes before that, you need to return -1...0 if they are the same, and 1 if this comes after that. Read the documentation of Comparator / Comparable for more information